# GAS sheets custom function no longer working and execution log showing 0s runtime with no information showing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Had a few custom functions used in a sheet that worked just fine until a few days ago. Now they all show "#ERROR!" on the sheet with the text bar explaining "Internal error executing the custom function". The most troubling issue I'm having is that when they fail it does not give me any information in the Executions log (see the screen grab below) with an Duration of 0s.

I have made sure the spelling is correct for all the functions and formulas already. As stated this sheet worked perfectly for months until a few days ago. There are 3 triggers (1 every 30 minutes,1 every hour, and 1 every 12 hours) but none of them involve any of these functions.

Any ideas???

```
function tickets_by_month(cellRange){
  /*
  Takes in the cell location of the working rows range. Populates the total tickets category cell if matching the selected cells month and year are correct

  input data eg (23~51) row 23 through 51 have the data we want
  */
  Logger.log(cellRange)                                                               // logs the cellrange input
  var ranges = cellRange.split("~")                                                   // returns the start and end with a ~ as a delimiter
  var endCell = Number(ranges[1])
  var total = 0                                                                       // running sum to be returned
  for(var startCell = Number(ranges[0]); startCell <= endCell; startCell ++){         // loop to sum the desired data to be returned
    total = total + escalationSS.getRange("B" + String(startCell)).getValue()         // escalationSS is another sheet in this workbook
    Logger.log(total)
  }
  return total
}
```

[image: Error log show executions]

[image]

Comment: Where is `escalationSS` defined?

Comment: yes, escalationSS is defined on another sheet in this workbook.

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
var escalationSS = ss.getSheetByName("Escalation by Day")

Comment: Google Sheets has a limit on simultaneous custom function executions (which, last I knew, was 30). In looking at your execution log, while we can't see the whole thing, it seems likely that you are exceeding this limit currently. The reasons it's evidencing now, at a glance, is that you are adding more of them with every month that goes by (four each month according to your screenshot), and that has likely caused your simultaneous executions to exceed 30 (which will only get worse with time). You'll need to rewrite more efficient scripts that process ranges, or explore regular formula options.

Comment: You should rewrite your function to accept a 2D range and return a 2D range as you are hitting too many simultaneous executions. You have 72 in this image alone

Comment: @ErikTyler thank you for the response. Was hoping it was not some sort of limit, but knowing this is better than guess. Looks like I will have to do the heavy lifting in the code rather than on the fly in each cell.

Comment: @Ihopethisishelpfultoyou thank you for the response. Back to the drawing board to implement a new approach. Appreciate your input.

Comment: Again, at a glance, this is something an array formula (no script) can handle more efficiently. If you'd like to explore that option, submit another post, provide a link to a sample spreadsheet and fill the grid with a few lines of hand-entered data that represent what you want returned. Explain in that post body and on sheet somewhere off to the side where that data is taken from and, if it isn't evident, how the results were determined. This will totally avoid any limits and likely be much faster as well.